# How can I combine several functions in the form of a DAG at runtime

Tags: c++, multithreading, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have several classes that each subclass an Operator.
An Operator has several inputs and outputs, of various types: image, number, string.
Each subclass implements a run() method that does the computation.
Now I would like to design a container for these Operators, to make bigger Operators from the simple ones.
The container should be as efficient as possible, so I'm planning to use threads. I have found an example in the Boost graph library that allows me to compute the order in which I should do the computation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/graph/doc/file_dependency_example.html , but I think there may be an even better way to do this: each operator could wait in a blocked state until all of its inputs are ready.
It would be good if the container subclassed Operator, allowing to recursively combine them.
I have a feeling this is a known design pattern.

Comment: "The container should be as efficient as possible, so I'm planning to use threads." - this makes no sense.  Unless each operation takes a long time to complete, you will likely worsen your performance by introducing threads.  I think you should get the basics right first.

Comment: Typical nodes include operations on large images, SQL requests on populated tables, ray-tracing and geometric computations on large set of points.

Comment: You're talking about (a special case of) the Actor model.  There is a huge amount of literature on this, and there are a multitude of design compromises to be made depending on your exact requirements.  I suggest you start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a design pattern that matches my description: [the composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

*The composite pattern describes that a group of objects are to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use TBB's flow graph?

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/09/08/the-intel-threading-building-blocks-flow-graph-is-now-fully-supported/